# SQl Aging report for previous year

Tags: t-sql

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6sKO.png) I need help to finish my query for aging report as 10/30/2022. My code work with the getdate() I need to replace the get date for 10/30/2022 so I can have the aging from that day to everything sitting on the system

It is a simple table

```
Select customer_id, trans_date, trans_amount, billing_period
, sum( case whn datediff(day,trans_dte, getdate()) between 0 and 30 then [amt] else 0 end) as [30_days]
group by billing_period, customer_id
```

I tried the listed is working but I need replace the getdate()

```
Select customer_id, trans_date, trans_amount, billing_period
, sum( case whn datediff(day,trans_dte, getdate()) between 0 and 30 then [amt] else 0 end) as [30_days]
group by billing_period, customer_id
```

Comment: What happen when you replace `getdate()` with the date ? The query is not working ?

Comment: HelloNo, I think I have to place a <=  somewhere

Comment: I am wondering if there is a better way to write it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your issue here. Please illustrate with some sample data, current result and the expected result

Comment: Is getdate a timestamp? so I am assuming that if I use getdate () my query is taking the system date. How I can make this work as 10/30/2022, do I need to use a parameter? that is my question, I will ilustrate it so you can understand and maybe help me

Comment: @Squirrel I am new in this site I added the link to the post. Thanks

Comment: you can use a variable like `declare @mydate date;` `set @mydate = '20221030';` then change your query to use the variable like `datediff(day,trans_dte, @mydate)`

Comment: Hi is not working is not bringing the amount, do I need to place the <= in front of the date, How I can write the query that bring everything sitting in the system form 10/30/2022  all the way back @Squirrel, it should be a way...

Comment: I really don't know what you want. As said in my earlier comment, show us some data from the table and the expected result and please do not use image, edit and update it in the question as text

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
declare @myDate datetime = '20221030'

Select customer_id, trans_date, trans_amount, billing_period
, sum( case whn datediff(day,trans_dte, @myDate) between 0 and 30 then [amt] else 0 end) as [30_days]
group by billing_period, customer_id
```